# How to output the values of interest output by five commands formatted in one line?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

There are 50 computers in the lab, each with two disks and two memory chips.
Everyday I need to check all the 100 disks and memory chips are not stolen.
I plan to achieve that with two steps:

**Step 1:** Write a batch file recording the disk count and memory chip count.

I have made it with the following script:

```
@echo off
echo >.\hardWareinfo.txt
(date/t & ipconfig & wmic cpu get name & wmic memorychip get capacity & wmic diskdrive get caption,size)>>.\hardWareinfo.txt
pause
```

It generates a text file containing something like this:

```
2018/04/05  
Windows IP Configuration
Ethernet Adaptor:

  DNS. . . . . . . : 

  IPV6 Address. . . . . . . . : fd80::aec3:fbdc:c5ae:119f%21

  IPV4 Address. . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100

  Subnet Mask. . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0

  Default Gateway. . . . . . . . . . . . :192.168.1.1


N a m e                                                                           I n t e l ( R )   C o r e ( T M )   i 5 - 7 4 0 0   C P U   @   3 . 0 0 G H z     

 C a p a c i t y         

 4 2 9 4 9 6 7 2 9 6     

 C a p t i o n                                                                 S i z e                       

 W D C   W D 1 0 E Z E X - 7 5 W N 4 A 0   S C S I   D i s k   D e v i c e     1 0 0 0 2 0 2 2 7 3 2 8 0
```

**Step 2:** Shorten the message into something like this:

```
{Date:2018/04/05,hostIP:192.168.1.100,CPU:Intel i5-7400,memorySize: 4294967296,diskSize:1000202273280}
```

How can I finish this step with a batch file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't work with a (temporary) file, just do it all in memory.
The "usual" way to get a command's output into a variable is a `for /f` loop.
Togheter with `find` and proper tokens and delimiters, you can quite precisely choose a proper substring.

I expanded it a bit to work also with multiple Network adapters, Dimms and Disks.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('date /t') do set "_dat=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('ipconfig^|find "IPv4"') do set "_ip=!_ip!+%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic cpu get name /value^|find "="') do set "_cpu=%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic memorychip get capacity /value^|find "="') do set "_mem=!_mem!+%%a"
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic diskdrive get caption^,size /value^|find "="') do set "_drv=!_drv!+%%a"
echo {Date:%_dat%,HostIP:%_ip:~1%,CPU:%_cpu%,MemSize:%_mem:~1%,DiskSize:%_drv:~1%}
```

Comment: Your suggestion  is really great. Thank you so much!

Comment: An optimization hint: The first `for /f` is not needed at all. Just replace `%_dat%` in last line by `%DATE%` to get output current local date in local date format. The __dynamic__ environment variable `DATE` is listed and briefly explained on last help page output on running in a command prompt window `set /?`.

Comment: Wasn't sure, whether `date /t` and `%date%` uses the same format, so there might have been a reason to use `date /t`. As I now know, they always have the same format, so @Mofi is right.